# validating username password django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
 username = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
 verified = models.BooleanField(default=0)
 def __str__(self):
    return self.username

class List(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 text = models.TextField(max_length=150)
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

I am trying to make a login page with username password to see a list that was created. I need help in validating the username password so that it logins with only the specific username password.

Comment: I suggest to follow the official Django tutorial from start to end.

Comment: Why are you trying to roll your own user model when you are clearly just starting out with Django??

Comment: Can u post your attempt?